# When $n\geq2$, let $a_n = \lceil \frac{n}{\pi}\rceil$ and let $b_n = \lceil{\csc({\frac{\pi}{n}})}\rceil$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

When $n\geq2$, let $a_n =\left \lceil \frac{n}{\pi}\right\rceil$ and let $b_n = \left\lceil{\csc({\frac{\pi}{n}})}\right\rceil$.

The terms of the sequences starting with $n = 2$ are:

{$a_n$} = $1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, ...$ and

{$b_n$} = $1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, ...$

Note that the sequences differ when $n=3$. Is it true that $a_n = b_n$ for all $n>3$?

Comment: That seems to be so!  To prove it, investigate the following question: "csc(x) appears to be very close to 1/x for x close to zero.  How close is this appriximation?"  And to get you started on THIS investigation, you can consider how closely x approximates sin(x) for x near zero.  Edit: oof, this question may be more subtle than I realized, you may need to use an estimate on how close a rational approximation p/q can be to pi, in terms of the size of the denominator q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When $n = 80143857$,
$$\begin{align}
n / \pi &= 25510581.9999999952976568107626972575226719258409876014\cdots, \\
\csc(\pi/n) &= 25510582.0000000018308933581165258478077895828199645771\cdots.
\end{align}$$
This counterexample was found with a small JavaScript code and verified by Wolfram|Alpha.